# Finding matrix form of Ellipsoid given general form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have data that I would like to fit with an ellipsoid and I am currently fitting it via the following Matlab commands:

```
xs = pts(:,1);
ys = pts(:,2);
zs = pts(:,3);

A0 = [xs.^2 ys.^2 zs.^2 xs.*ys ys.*zs xs.*zs xs ys zs ones(size(xs))];
B0 = [ones(size(xs))];

A = A0'*A0;
B = A0'*B0;

X = A\B;
```

but I am going to rewrite this into `C++` later. For now, I have `X` which are the parameters for the general form of an ellipsoid in 3 space. How do I now turn these parameters into a `3x3` matrix to calculate $$ (x-C)^T \cdot A \cdot (x-C) $$ so that I can efficiently calculate if a point $x$ is inside the ellipsoid centered at $C$? Furthermore, $C$ is not any part of the original calculation of these parameters, so do I need to move `xs`, `ys`, and `zs` to the original before performing the LS fit?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually defined an ellipsoid with

$(x-c)^{T}A(x-c)$

An ellipsoid is defined by an inequality

$(x-c)^{T}A(x-c) \leq 1$.

Keep in mind that there isn't an ellipsoid of this form corresponding to every vector $X$ that you might get out of the least squares solution.

If there is a solution, then the quadratic terms are associated with $X(1)$, $\ldots$, $X(6)$.

$A=[X(1) \; X(4) \; X(6); X(4) \; X(2) \; X(5); X(6) \; X(5) \; X(3)]$

Then solve

$-2AC=[X(7); \; X(8); \; X(9)]$

$C^{T}C=X(10)$

If there is no such solution, or $A$ isn't positive definite, then $X$ doesn't correspond to an ellipsoid.

In practice this is likely to fail to produce a solution.  There are other approaches to fitting ellipsoids to data that do work, but they aren't based on on first fitting a least squares quadratic form as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Having all the points contained within ellipsoid reminds me of the minimum volume ellipsoid problem. This is easily solved with [Khachiyan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method). The MATLAB code is available [here](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid). Having said that, I think it is worth reminding you that matrix $A$ is actually the inverse covariance matrix.